# Why do some of my participants get sent a receipt when I update event details via a profile form

Tags: civievent

I'm using CiviCRM V4.4.13 and Drupal 7.41.

I have created a profile for batch updating several custom fields and the status of participants on our events. However, some participants seem to get sent a receipt after saving the updates (around 5-10% of participants) as if we had gone into their participant record and selected send confirmation and receipt. Is this a bug or is this expected behavior because of X reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you update the status of multiple participants using a profile, any participant whose status is changed from a non-counted status to a counted status or vice versa will be sent an email.

Go to **Administer > CiviEvent > Particpant Statuses** to check which statuses are counted and which aren't. (In this case "counted" means "included in count of total registrations for the event".)

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you haven't enabled **Online Registration => Confirmation Email** in the Event Configure page

please make sure does all the member has a email Id
Also please make sure **"On Hold?"** is switched off for all the member